# Silverlight 3 DataForm - How to populate DataFormComboBoxField from enumeration

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, dataform

XAML

```
 <df:DataForm x:Name="MobCrud"
        AutoEdit="True"
        AutoCommit="True"
        AutoGenerateFields="False"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"       
        CommandButtonsVisibility="All"
        Header="Mob Details" 
        CanUserAddItems="True"
        CanUserDeleteItems="True"
        CurrentItem="{StaticResource newMob}"
    >
<df:DataForm.Fields>
   <df:DataFormTextField  Binding="{Binding Name}" FieldLabelContent="Name" />
   <df:DataFormTextField Binding="{Binding Title}" FieldLabelContent="Title"/>
   <df:DataFormComboBoxField  x:Name="AuraList" Binding="{Binding Aura}"  FieldLabelContent="Aura"/>
</df:DataForm.Fields>
```

Code:

```
public enum Auras
{
    Holy,
    Fire,
    Frost,
}

public class MobDetail : IEditableObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Auras Aura { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() { return Name; }

    public void BeginEdit(){}
    public void EndEdit(){}
    public void CancelEdit(){}
}
```

The DataForm ItemsSource is bound to an ObservableCollection()

What do I need to do to populate and initialize the dropdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is to use a converter:

```
<df:DataFormComboBoxField  
     x:Name="AuraList"
     Binding="{Binding Aura, Mode=TwoWay,
               Converter={StaticResource enumSelectedValueConverter}}"
     FieldLabelContent="Aura"/>
```

and set the ItemsSource on the form Loaded event

```
(MobCrud.Fields[2] as DataFormComboBoxField).ItemsSource =
                 Enums.GetStringArray(typeof(Auras));
```

See here for the full story:

[Creating-Rich-Data-Forms-in-Silverlight-3-Customization](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Creating-Rich-Data-Forms-in-Silverlight-3-Customization.aspx)